# Where do I store a integrative feature (file) in multi-modul maven project?

Tags: java, maven, junit, cucumber

I created a multi-modul maven project. After I implemented and (manually) tested a prototype I'm confident about the business model and want to improve and expand the functionality. Because of the high complexity I do want to ensure the quality of my project with BDD.

This is a representative structure for my project:

```
|restaurant
   |-kitchen
      |-src
         |-main
         |-test
            |-resources
                prepareStarter.feature
                prepareFood.feature
                prepareDesert.feature
   |-management
      |-src
         |-main
         |-test
            |-resources
                calculateProfit.feature
                prepareWorkSchedule.feature
   |-eatingroom
      |-src
         |-main
         |-test
            |-resources
                welcomeGuests.feature
                serveFood.feature
                serveDrinks.feature
   |-pom.xml
```

When I want to write a feature to ensure the integration of all three (example) projects, where do I put the feature file?

At the moment my Restaurant project is `packaging` as `pom`. Do I have to change it to java and put the feature files in `|-restaurant|-src|-test|-resources`?

Comment: You can add new project at root level(can call it smoketest-project or smth like this), add kitchen, management and eatingroom dependencies to it and perfrom tests there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better to keep your high level project as a `pom` module. It's very common in multi-module project to have a dedicated module containing only integration tests which covers cross module scenarios. I think the same applies to your project and the BDD features. By doing so your project structure would be something like this:

```
|restaurant
   |-kitchen
      |-src
         |-main
         |-test
            |-resources
                prepareStarter.feature
                prepareFood.feature
                prepareDesert.feature
   |-management
      |-src
         |-main
         |-test
            |-resources
                calculateProfit.feature
                prepareWorkSchedule.feature
   |-eatingroom
      |-src
         |-main
         |-test
            |-resources
                welcomeGuests.feature
                serveFood.feature
                serveDrinks.feature
   |-bdd-tests
      |-src
         |-main
         |-test
            |-resources
                cross-module-1.feature
                cross-module-2.feature
                cross-module-3.feature
   |-pom.xml
```

It's up to you to decide if you need to have a single module containing all integration and BDD tests together or a dedicated module for each type of tests. It depends on how many tests/features you have.